# Case Statement where duplicate ID Has different statuses and I cant get it to return as I would like to

Tags: sql, sql-server

I really hope someone can assist me with this issue.

**Scenario:**

New column to come in (CASE STATEMENT):

**When the current answer is IN**

('Auto Decline', 'Decline Before AIP', 'Decline After AIP', 'Withdrawn by Bank', 'Withdrawn By Origination After AIP', 'Withdrawn By Origination Before AIP')

**THEN it Should say ‘Dormant’**

**When current answer in** 
('Quotation Offer Received - Awaiting Acceptance',
'Quotation Received - Awaiting Acceptance',
'Further Credit Info Sent To Bank - Awaiting AIP',                                                                           'AIP Accepted - Awaiting Quotation',
'Consultant Pending - Awaiting Feedback',
'Further Credit Info Sent To Bank - Awaiting Quotation',
'AIP Offer Received - Awaiting Quotation',
'Pending Acceptance Of Quotation',
'Sect Title Register Not Opened - Awaiting Closure',
'Subject To Sale - Awaiting Closure',
'Further Credit Info Required',
'Arbitration - Awaiting AIP',
'SFM Credit Appeal',
'Awaiting Amendment To Quotation',
'Awaiting AIP',
'AIP Received - Further Credit Info Required',
'AIP Offer Received - Awaiting Acceptance',
'Arbitration - Awaiting Quotation',
'AIP Received - Awaiting Acceptance',
'AIP Received - Awaiting Quotation',
'Channel Conflict',
'No AMS')

**THEN it should say ‘Active’**

**Here is the real ISSUE:**

When that ID only has the dormant status it should show dormant, but when an ID has one or more on the Active answers then all the records for that ID should be Active.
To give you an idea on the result I'm getting:

[image]

If you cant see the picture here is the result I am getting:

```
ApplicationID |  AnswerType         |REFStatus
1001145       |Decline Before AIP   |Dormant
1001145       |Decline Before AIP   |Dormant
1001145       |WithDrawn by Bank    |Dormant
1060906       |Decline Before AIP   |Dormant
1060906       |Decline Before AIP   |Dormant
1060906       |Decline Before AIP   |Dormant
1060906       |SFM Credit Appeal    |Active
```

Here is the result I am looking for:

```
ApplicationID |  AnswerType         |REFStatus
1001145       |Decline Before AIP   |Dormant
1001145       |Decline Before AIP   |Dormant
1001145       |WithDrawn by Bank    |Dormant
1060906       |Decline Before AIP   |Active
1060906       |Decline Before AIP   |Active
1060906       |Decline Before AIP   |Active
1060906       |SFM Credit Appeal    |Active
```

**CODE:**

```
SELECT app.ApplicationID, bankans.AnswerType,
--This CASE is fine---
CASE 
WHEN bankans.AnswerType IN ('Auto Decline',
                            'Decline Before AIP',
                            'Decline After AIP', 
                            'Withdrawn by Bank',
                            'Withdrawn By Origination After AIP',
                            'Withdrawn By Origination Before AIP')
THEN 'Dormant'

---Here is where my problem lies. Getting all the rows of the ID to say Active, when the ID has at least one active status.

WHEN bankans.AnswerType IN ('Auto Decline',
                            'Decline Before AIP',
                            'Decline After AIP', 
                            'Withdrawn by Bank',
                            'Withdrawn By Origination After AIP',
                            'Withdrawn By Origination Before AIP')
---These are the Answers that would have an Active REFStatus below
    OR bankans.AnswerType IN ('Quotation Offer Received - Awaiting Acceptance',
                                'Quotation Received - Awaiting Acceptance',
                                'Further Credit Info Sent To Bank - Awaiting AIP',
                                'AIP Accepted - Awaiting Quotation',
                                'Consultant Pending - Awaiting Feedback',
                                'Further Credit Info Sent To Bank - Awaiting Quotation',
                                'AIP Offer Received - Awaiting Quotation',
                                'Pending Acceptance Of Quotation',
                                'AIP Received Awaiting Quotation',
                                'Sect Title Register Not Opened - Awaiting Closure',
                                'Subject To Sale - Awaiting Closure',
                                'Further Credit Info Required', 'SFM Credit Appeal')

                                THEN 'Active'

                                END AS 'REFStatus'

FROM Import.OobaApplication AS app
LEFT OUTER JOIN Import.OobaBankAnswer AS bankans ON app.ApplicationID = bankans.ApplicationID
ORDER BY app.ApplicationID
```

I would really appreciate the help. Please let me know if you might need any other info.

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement.

Comment: Your question is the diametric opposite of minimal; the query is more than a hundred lines long.  If you have an error from the `CASE` expression, then tell us what it is and provide a minimal example.

Comment: Sorry about that, just thought I'd give as much info as possible. I have added only the "case expression"

Comment: Show us the desired output please

Comment: When you say "ID" in your question text, do you mean `app.ApplicationID` in the presented query?

Comment: And are you saying that you want all result rows in each partition to have the same `REF # Status`?

Comment: Yes exactly that. If you have a look at the picture. The part that I highlighted should have the same REF # Status and yes the ID in app.ApplicationID

Comment: You could also add a simplified/executable query that demonstrates your problem. *you put some effort...* -> *we put some effort...* kinda thing

Comment: I will put in all the effort I can, no worries :) I'm just not sure what you mean by  simplified/executable query Stephen?

Comment: You've (mercifully) cut down the query presented, but you seem not to quite have gotten the point about that.  We're looking for a [mcve].  You're now doing better (though still not great) in the "minimal" department, but that comes at the expense of the "complete" department.  It's still hard to determine what's going on, or what *should* go on.  For a good and answerable question, you probably need to devise a simpler model problem to ask about.

Comment: No problem. I will get that to you asap

Comment: One other critique if I may, in the specs, you outline two conditions, but in the code, there are three WHEN expressions.  That last one doesn't make sense to me.  But the question seems pretty straightforward, if you have 8 of the top responses from the bank and one of them falls in the "active" category, you want all of them to report as "active"?  Also, I can't see the picture but that might be a problem on my side.  If I understand the request, I'd have another question for you, do you really want to see all 8 answers or do you just want to report back that this id is active or dormant?

Comment: Hi paulbarbin, I am working on sending the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I understand that there are 3 When expressions, but that was just to show you what I have tried. You understand the question perfectly. The Bank answers are shown on the report in it's own column. I just want the report to state if the ID is Dormant or Active in an extra column. Is there any way that I can send you the picture? Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Everything updated. Hope this will help you to assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @App table (ApplicationID int)
insert @App values (1001145),(1060906)

declare @AppAnswer table (ApplicationID int, AnswerType varchar(max))
insert @AppAnswer values (1001145, 'Decline Before AIP'), (1001145, 'Withdrawn by Bank'), (1001145, 'Decline Before AIP'),
                         (1060906, 'Decline Before AIP'), (1060906, 'Decline Before AIP'), (1060906, 'SFM Credit Appeal')

;with CTE (ApplicationID, AnswerType, Stat) As 
(
    select app.ApplicationID, bankans.AnswerType, 
           CASE WHEN bankans.AnswerType IN ('Auto Decline',
                            'Decline Before AIP',
                            'Decline After AIP', 
                            'Withdrawn by Bank',
                            'Withdrawn By Origination After AIP',
                            'Withdrawn By Origination Before AIP')
                THEN 'Dormant'
                ELSE 'Active' 
            END AS Stat
    FROM @App AS app
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @AppAnswer AS bankans ON app.ApplicationID = bankans.ApplicationID  
)
SELECT ApplicationID, AnswerType, IIF(count(*) over (partition by ApplicationID) > count(Stat) over (partition by ApplicationID, Stat), 'Active', 'Dormant')
FROM CTE
```

the If statement checks if the `count` of statuses is different to the `count` of IDs.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, that works perfectly. Sorry for the delay in response. Just one last question. Lest say I only want the result to show the Distinct Application ID that has the Dormant status as when I use the WHERE clause.. It only allows me to use the CTE data and not the Data from the IIF statement. Once again thank you for the assistance :)

Comment: Hi Stephen, Sorry didn't know you can accept the answers. Can I rate you somewhere or something?

Comment: Accepting the answer is good enough. But to answer your question, you can rate an answer by clicking on the up arrow, as **useful**, and down arrow  if "**not useful**"